# Trying to install VS 2015 w/ update 1 after update 2 was causing major issues

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Last week update 2 was officially released for Visual Studio 2015. In a desire to stay up-to-date I installed it and when I did I started having some functionality broken with visual studio. I removed the update through add/remove programs but was still getting the stalling out and some broken functionality. I tried to roll back using windows restore to before last Friday (when I installed it), this made functionality much worse so I had to uninstall.

I wrote it off as a glitch with the upgrade and grabbed a fresh install online of VS2015 preloaded with update 2. Sadly I still had issues, particularly now with doing migrations.

I decided I had enough, it wasn’t worth the hassle of getting Update 2 to work, so now I am trying to install visual studio with update 1 (what I had on there before Friday) it doesn't work. I can open and run the installer for VS2015 with update 2 and that works fine, but when open the same installer I used a few months ago that had update 1 I select the modules I want and click install that's when I get this error:

"Setup detected an issue during the operation. please click below to check for a solution and help us improve the set up experience" (but it only gives me the option to close program)

I tried running the visual studio 2015 installer with the “/uninstall /force” flags in case it left something. I went to the “program files (x86)” folder and deleted what’s left of the visual studio 14.0 folder (which is 2015) but to no avail. In a last ditch effort I even tried removing all visual studio settings out of the user/appdata/roaming and user/appdata/local folders. I uninstalled ANYTHING that was installed in my programs since last Friday.

Lastly, I am looking at the log of one of the failed install attempts and the only line with the word “error” is this one:
[15BC:1528][2016-04-06T22:48:02]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I don’t know what that means. I see people having that error WHILE in visual studio, but I'm getting it for the installer.

TL:DR I want to install VS2015 U1 after upgrading to VS2015 U2 and having to uninstall but it won't let me install.

Edit: someone suggested system restore to restore my computer to a date in before I upgraded to update 2 but with all the installing and uninstalling attempts yesterday I blew away anything before then

Comment: Some similar happenned to me two days ago with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. My partners had no problems with similar configuration than me. Tried same things as you and the repair option with no success. In my case I finally had my whole computer reinstalled. Hope it won´t be necessary for you. In the new installation I could installa Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 with no issues.

Comment: Yea, I tried to reinstall instead of update but that didn't work. I am completely fine going back to update 1. I look back now and aside from a little curiosity with cordova there was no reason to get update 2.