# Upgraded to VS 2015 update 2 and having web dev issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2015

Ever since I upgraded to Update 2 of VS2015 Whenever I open up a a js file I get an error (the excerpt from the error log is below. My JS files seem to work fine, color coding works as well as auto-complete BUT for some reason my cshtml is not working with Intellisense at all; no auto-complete, ignores break points, and no color coding. I have reset my user settings as well as uninstalled and reinstalled (several times) making sure I have web development tools selected. Not being able to use Intellisense is greatly hindering my work.

Any suggestions you can provide would be great, Windows 10 is not letting me install VS 2015 with update 1 so if I can't get this to work I need to format.

```
 <entry>
    <record>672</record>
    <time>2016/04/11 23:25:24.082</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>673</record>
    <time>2016/04/11 23:25:24.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral][Expected 1 export(s) with contract name &quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.MiscellaneousFilesWorkspace&quot; but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.]:{   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition importDefinition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T](String contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)}</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.MiscellaneousFilesWorkspace" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>674</record>
    <time>2016/04/11 23:25:24.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.MiscellaneousFilesWorkspace" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Update 2 but I have not seen this issue yet. Instead of attempting to go back to Update 1, have you considered uninstalling completely and then reinstalling the latest VS2015 with Update 2?

Instead of downloading the smaller installer, try downloading the ISO file instead so that you have the entire installer on your local machine before kicking off the install.

Let me know if you have any trouble finding the ISO file on the VS website since it's a little tricky to find it.

Comment: These are all wonderful ideas! I have tried both the online installer and the iso for update 1, there is something on there seeing update 2 is on the machine even though I did a force uninstall (in case that is more complete and even deleted the VS2015 folder.
If you want more details there please click below, it didn't get much love.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476676/trying-to-install-vs-2015-w-update-1-after-update-2-was-causing-major-issues

Comment: Ok, I just checked it out but I don't know if I can add anything else that may help. I went with Update 2 for the Windows 10 preview SDK and Xbox Dev Mode. I've continued to use it for ASP .NET web dev, but haven't had the issues you had. Maybe you can try a reinstall or a second machine or a VM?

Comment: I installed on another machine with update 1 so i could continue work until we figure it out... but I think I am just at the point of wiping. I hate that I couldn't figure out how to just completely destroy any trace of the visual studio with update 2 install and install VS2015 with update 1 - something is still persisting that won't let me... also tried clearing temp files.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the updates. It's helpful for others who may be having the same issues.

Comment: Totally, I hope it does help others. Since it seems others aren't facing this issue I am going to assume it is not on Microsoft's hotfix list so I will probably format soon and install with update 1. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, the problem extended farther than I thought, its not just CSHTML that isn't recognized but all C# as a whole, maybe more.

Comment: I searched for "Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense not working" and found some various workarounds. One of them suggested checking some selections under Options and it appears to have worked for VS2013 and lower. In case it works for VS2015 as well, here's a link: http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008

Comment: Also try submitting your question to MSDN forums. I've seen some various responses there, for earlier releases of VS2015.

Comment: New devopment, I found it was only with one (rather large) solution, my other solutions don't seem to have this issue. Some of the others were mvc 4 so not seeing that as an issue, could it be a nuget package? That seems to be the only thing I can think of. My data is on the chopping block tomorrow night, if I can't figure it out by then it gets reset.

Comment: If you suspect there is something wrong with Nuget packages, try your solution on a different machine, maybe one of your own or a coworker's machine. That should tell you right away, whether it's your installation or specific packages in your solution.

Comment: None of my coworkers have update 2 installed and at this point all of them are too scared to do so. It just got wiped and I plan to make a VM for it to do some testing with update 2... but at this point it doesn't offer anything to offset the risk.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the continued issues. I'll pass on the above info internally at Microsoft, and I would also suggest using the feedback tool from within Visual Studio to report your experience and issues.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to find others that has my issue but it must have been some one off quark.